# Categorized shapes for one attribute and categorized colour for another attribute

Tags: qgis, point, style, rule-based

I can find similar questions but not the same and I'm struggling to figure it out.

I have species data for an area. The attributes I'm interested in displaying are the Species Group and the Species Name.

I would like the Species Group to be displayed as different shapes and the species names displayed as different categorized random colours.

I have tried categorizing the species groups and manually setting the shape, changing to rule based styling, 'Refine Selected Rules' then 'Add categories to rule' for a single species group to classify the Species Names but I end up with all species categorized including species not in that group.

Any help/ideas welcome.

---

I followed this by going to layer properties > Symbology > Categorized > Value = species_name > symbol >Marker > Simple Marker

Then i edited the shape I followed this by going to layer properties > Symbology > Categorized > Value = species_name > symbol >Marker > Simple Marker

Then i edited the shape see below
[image: image of shape expression]

But when i go back to symbology and classify the species names, they are all the same shape still.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual result on the map ? it's only there that each case related marker will appear thanks to the override. The symbol editor/legend does not know about the conditional formatting

Comment: Ahh very clever. It does show on the map. However, the legend still shows them all as simple markers. How do I make the legend catch up with the override?

Comment: Legend does not know the override either, or at least I don't know if there is a workaround, might be a topic for another dedicated question. Maybe in Layouts with 'data defined legend labels' bit that's just an assumption

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to data drive the shape with your `group` field data.
In the style properties of your layer, go to the shape selection area for your point layer and click on the dropdown icon at the left :

[image: shape data driven]

then edit the expression and paste an expression like that :

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "group" = 'group1' THEN 'square'
  WHEN "group" = 'group2' THEN 'diamond'
  ELSE 'triangle'
END
```

Here the field name is `"group"`, so replace with the exact name of your field, and create as many rules `WHEN ... THEN` as differents groups.
You can have the shape category by hovering the shape and wait for a tool hint (like the <kbd>octagon</kbd> in the screenshot above).

Then you can style your layer by category, random colors, on the `"species_name"` field.

Comment: Was about to post the same answer. Legend won't explicitely show which symbol belongs to which group (unless there's a tip to handle that). This might be solved by a similar approach with relevant SVG symbols

Comment: an other solution, which takes more time, is to categorize the layer on the expression `"group" || ' ' || "species_name"` and affect a symbol manually ...